# anyone has usable webdav client library or framework for iphone app?

Tags: iphone, webdav

I need to send a file to webdav server from iphone app, it's include the function of create folder, update file, delete file. so i want a webdav client framework for iphone or static library, which could used at my iphone app.

- I have found some code, such as ConnectionKit, it hasn't been updated in years, and i have not passed the compiling for iOS device 4.1.-
- I also check the c library, such as neon, but i could not port it as static library for iOS.-
- I also checked Davlib, since it had been used MAC os, but i don't not know how to use CodeWarrior-

anyone have idea or anyone has the useful webdav? please help me.

Thanks!

new tags: conectionkit davlib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the [flycode WebDAV implementation](http://github.com/ccgus/flycode/tree/master/WebDAV) working on an iPhone with minimal changes, though I never used it for production code.

Comment: Thanks! 1. i think it could work for the webdav server that has not the authentication, but how i could send the user name and password for this module? 2. by the way, it works on MAC, how could i do for iPhone, do you know the network operaion could support iphone and if i used it, i could port it as a static library for iphone??

Comment: I simply added the FM* and ISO* files directly to my project and added `#define debug NSLog` to my pch file. There are a couple deprecated methods that need fixing, but I think that's it. (I don't remember the exact details, but the code is largely iPhone compatible as is. The changes I made were minor.)

Comment: `FMWebDAVRequest` has username and password properties you can set to handle authentication.

Comment: I thinks authentication is ok for me, since the time for NSRunLoop is not correct, now i change the time for it and it is ok, i will added it into iphone project and test it. if it works, i may add a repository at github to share my succeed. thanks you!

Comment: hi all, the code on MAC of iphone simulater is ok, but on iphone machine, it failed since it could not get response after create folder, the program hangs at that place.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently having good luck with this client: http://code.google.com/p/wtclient/.

Comment: thanks, i have learned this project and add more command to fix my request. it is good.

Answer (score 1):

I just started using `DZWebDAVClient`. It needs `AFNetworking` to work though.
Had no issues setting it up and has a block based API.
https://github.com/zwaldowski/DZWebDAVClient

Another recommendation i found elsewhere is `ConnectionKit`
https://github.com/karelia/ConnectionKit

*(Reposting my answer to a different question - [WebDav client library for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883075/webdav-client-library-for-ios))*

Comment: Thank you very much, but wtclient is worked for me. it's so simple and just supported for webdev client. i recommend it.