# WebDav client library for iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, webdav

Is there any WebDav client implementation for iOS ?

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [WTclient](http://code.google.com/p/wtclient/).

Comment: As described on that linked page; `svn checkout http://wtclient.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ wtclient-read-only`

Comment: Thank you Till. Did you succeeded in using it ? I set up a username and password in settings of the iphone, fill in the strings that are in the textfields's placeholders, i access the same link on my mac, it says "Establishing connection" on iPhone, but it fails on my mac with message: "An error occurred while processing your request.
Reference #97.c61ac451.1346271642.187cc1f6"

Answer (score 4):

try [WTClient](http://code.google.com/p/wtclient/), it's written in objective-c.

Comment: have you succeeded in using it ?

Comment: I never really looked into it, but i figured it would be good starting point. sorry i'm not of more help.

Answer (score 2):

I just started using `DZWebDAVClient`. It needs `AFNetworking` to work though.
Had no issues setting it up and has a block based API.

https://github.com/zwaldowski/DZWebDAVClient

Another recommendation i found elsewhere is `ConnectionKit`
https://github.com/karelia/ConnectionKit