# WebDAV communication (Objective-C/Cocoa)

Tags: objective-c, ios, webdav

I've been searching the web, and iOS don't have some great WebDAV framework. I need to log-in into the server and send/receive some files, but I realized that this isn't really simple.

Anyone with some simple tip/solution to **upload/receive** files using WebDAV?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WebDav client library for iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883075/webdav-client-library-for-ios)

Comment: @Caleb Actually, the WTClient doesn't work with me, that's why I'm asking here... I've been searching in the web and nothing is working.

Comment: You'll get better answers then if you explain what you've already tried (such as WTClient) and what trouble you're having. Otherwise, people like me will try to help by suggesting things that you've already tried. At the same time, we won't know enough to suggest solutions to the problems you've had.